# Why is this systemd service preventing PortAudio to query audio devices?

Tags: systemd, python, audio, udev

I have a very strange problem since a few hours with what seems really two *really unrelated things*: a Systemd service (doing nothing!) and the listing of available audio devices.

More precisely I have a service `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` which runs as soon as possible on boot:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test
DefaultDependencies=false
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /root/foo.py
WorkingDirectory=/root/
[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

`foo.py` simply queries the audio devices with the [`sounddevice`](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/) Python module (wrapper around PortAudio):

```
import sounddevice
print(sounddevice.query_devices(0))
```

**This perfectly works and returns 1 audio device.**

**However, when I add a second service** `/etc/systemd/system/usb-mount@.service` that does really nothing (initially it did mount the USB devices [with this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681379/usb-flash-drives-automatically-mounted-headless-computer), but I even removed this part to do the debugging, and the problem is still there!):

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount USB Drive on %i
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ls         # note: normally here we should automount USB devices, but the bug is still there with just a simple ls that does nothing!
```

which is started by this udev rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start usb-mount@%k.service"
```

... then the querying of audio devices fails with:

```
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo foo.sh[116]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sounddevice.py", line 778, in __init__
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo foo.sh[116]:     extra_settings, samplerate)
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo foo.sh[116]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2571, in _get_stream_parameters
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo foo.sh[116]:     info = query_devices(device)
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo foo.sh[116]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sounddevice.py", line 569, in query_devices
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo foo.sh[116]:     raise PortAudioError('Error querying device {0}'.format(device))
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo foo.sh[116]: sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error querying device 0
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo systemd[1]: foo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 10 22:51:27 foo systemd[1]: foo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**How to debug this problem?** The fact that PortAudio is able to query informations about an audio device should be totally unrelated to this second Systemd service (started by `udev`) which does really nothing, don't you think so?

I am really clueless about this bug linking two totally unrelated things.

---

Note: removing `DefaultDependencies=false` seems to solve the problem. But I thought `DefaultDependencies=false` was necessary to avoid the service to wait for networking to be ready before starting. Is there [another solution without this option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681443/dont-wait-for-networking-to-be-ready-before-starting-the-systemd-service)?

Comment: Relevant discussion here: https://lightrun.com/answers/bastibe-soundcard-import-soundcard-throws-an-error-when-run-through-a-systemd-service

Spoiler: no resolution

Comment: Bug report (presently unresolved): https://github.com/bastibe/SoundCard/issues/133